# Magento show products "new_from_date" first in list.phtml

Tags: magento, sorting, collections

i try to show in my list.phtml the product "new_from_date" first of all the other..

I try to override the List.php block class adding

```
   $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date','desc');
```

But not work...
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is getSortBy magic method in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List block. And in

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
```

you may see that code

```
if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
    $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
}

...

$toolbar->setCollection($collection);
```

Then go to toolbar (Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar)

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
...
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
```

I think this is a problem. You may try to override protected function _beforeToHtml() in your block and change

```
if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
    $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
}
```

to

```
$collection->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date','desc');
```

or may be observe 'catalog_block_product_list_collection' and change sort there. These are only suggestions, but as I can see the problem is directly in _beforeToHtml() and in toolbar.